# Can EF Core configure a "real" One-To-One relation where both ends are required?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

The [EF Core documentation about One-To-One relations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns) says: *"When configuring the relationship with the Fluent API, you use the `HasOne` and `WithOne` methods."* A closer look shows that this configures One-To-ZeroOrOne or ZeroOrOne-To-ZeroOrOne relations depending on whether `IsRequired` is used or not. Example:

```
public class ParentEntity
{
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
  public ChildEntity Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildEntity
{
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
  public ParentEntity Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The derived context class contains:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<ParentEntity>().HasOne(p => p.Child).WithOne(d => d.Parent)
                                     .HasForeignKey<ChildEntity>("ParentFk").IsRequired();
}
```

With this configuration, `context.SaveChanges` fails after `context.Add(new ChildEntity())` as expected (with `SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ParentFk' ...` because of `IsRequired`) but succeeds after `context.Add(new ParentEntity())` and `context.Add(new ChildEntity() { Parent = new ParentEntity() })`, i.e., the `ParentEntity-ChildEntity` relation is One-To-ZeroOrOne. In other words: the parent of a child is required, the child of a parent is optional.

Is there a way to configure a "real" One-To-One relation where both ends are required?

Maybe this cannot be enforced within the database. But can it be enforced by EF Core? (BTW: It can be enforced by EF6.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure a "real" One-To-One relation where both ends are required?

At the time of writing (EF Core 2.1.2), the answer is (unfortunately) negative.

The [Required and Optional Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships) section of the documentation says:

> You can use the Fluent API to configure whether the relationship is required or optional. Ultimately this controls whether the foreign key property is required or optional.

There is also a closed issue [EF Core 2: One to One Required Not Being Enforced (also Navigation no longer needed?) #9152](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9152) asking the same question, and part of the response is:

> when a relationship is made "Required" it means that a dependent entity cannot exist without an associated principal entity. This is done my making the FK non-nullable--i.e. the FK value must reference some principal entity.
>
> However, it says nothing about the principal entity existing without the dependent. This is always possible because there isn't really any way to restrict it when working with partially loaded graphs. (This was the same with the old stack, although there were some situations where the state manager would, almost arbitrarily, stop certain things happening.) With stronger semantics applied to aggregates that limit partially loading of graphs it may be possible to enforce such a restriction in the future, but that isn't done yet.

Comment: Thanks for the issue link. I didn't know that in EF6 there is "the EF _validation_ feature, which EF Core doesn't have" (quote from the [comment](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9152#issuecomment-314562789) by @ajcvickers). This explains why in EF6 [Configuring a Relationship Where Both Ends Are Required (One-to-One)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#configuring-a-relationship-where-both-ends-are-required-one-to-one) is possible, but not in EF Core (at least, not yet).